# Show $\int _ 0 ^\infty \frac {\sin ( x^2 + ax )}{ x } dx$ converges for $a\ge 0$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, laplace-transform

I want to show that $f(a) = \int _ 0 ^\infty \frac {\sin ( x^2 + ax )}{ x } dx$ converges for all $a \ge 0$ and $f$ is continuous on $[0, \infty ) $.

Comment: It probably converges for the same reason $\sum(-1)^n\frac1n$ converges.  The changing sine of sin will cause the necessary cancellation.  Because just $\frac1x$ is not integrable.

Comment: try to premultiply the integrand with e^(-sx). This is a Laplace transform. Now put s=0.